# Anonymise a local git repository?

Tags: git, anonymity

I have a local git repository that I've done quite a bit of work on, with a number of commits that I'd like to retain. Unfortunately, while the code is reasonable reusable, I included some sensitive data (database names/user/passwords) in a very early commit. I would like to change the entire history to anonymise the sensitive data, while retaining the general history structure. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will help:

- [Remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)
- [Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option%3a-filter-branch)

Comment: Yes. History re-writing is they key. I made a backup repo (just in case), and then ran `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'sed -i "s/sensitive data/clean data/g *' HEAD`, and that removed everything from the whole tree. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Remove them from the repository, then commit. You then need to squash all the commits from when the files were added to when they were removed. You can see a good explanation about that [here](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) which in short suggests using `git rebase -i`.

Comment: I am aware I can squash commits, but that will remove the history I was talking about.